# How to output a specific Map value's key in alphabetical order in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, alphabetical

I'm trying to print out the contents of a specific map value, but in alphabetical letter based on the letters inside of the brackets.

Below is the original output which doesn't meet what I'm trying to do.

> ```
>    |
>    Element [ab] Element 2
>    Element [a] Element 1
>    Element [b] Element 3
>    Element [e] Element 6
>    Element [d] Element 5
>    Element [c] Element 4
>    |
> ```

Now the output I'm trying to get is below, which would be using the printSelectiveAlphabetic() function

> ```
>    |
>    Element [a] Element 1
>    Element [ab] Element 2
>    Element [b] Element 3
>    Element [c] Element 4
>    Element [d] Element 5
>    Element [e] Element 6
>   |
> ```

So how do I adjust my printSelectiveAlphabetic() function to get this desired output?

Code Below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//Prints whole map
void printMap(map<string, vector<string>>  mapVar) {
    cout << endl;
    map<string ,vector<string>> :: iterator it;
    for(it=mapVar.begin();it !=mapVar.end();++it)
      {
       cout << it->first << endl;
       for(auto it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); ++it2) {
            cout << *it2 << " ";
            cout << endl;}
      }
}

//Prints specific value of map
void printSelectiveMap(vector<string> v, map<string, vector<string>> helpMap) {
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
    string searchValue = v[0];
        for (auto map_iter = helpMap.cbegin(); map_iter != helpMap.cend(); ++map_iter) {
            if (v[0] == map_iter->first) {
                    int count = 0;
                    for (auto vec_iter = map_iter->second.cbegin(); vec_iter != map_iter->second.cend(); ++vec_iter) {
                            cout << "\t" << searchValue << " " << *vec_iter << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
}

//A copy of the above function, what I'm trying to change to have alaphabetical output
//This needs to use the letters, not the numbers in the vector to implement this
void printSelectiveAlphabetic(vector<string> v, map<string, vector<string>> helpMap) {
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
    string searchValue = v[0];
        for (auto map_iter = helpMap.cbegin(); map_iter != helpMap.cend(); ++map_iter) {
            if (v[0] == map_iter->first) {
                    int count = 0;
                    for (auto vec_iter = map_iter->second.cbegin(); vec_iter != map_iter->second.cend(); ++vec_iter) {
                            cout << "\t" << searchValue << " " << *vec_iter << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
}

int main() {

    map<string, vector<string>> maphelp;

    vector<string> vect;
    vect.push_back("[ab] Element 2");
    vect.push_back("[a] Element 1");
    vect.push_back("[b] Element 3");
    vect.push_back("[e] Element 6");
    vect.push_back("[d] Element 5");
    vect.push_back("[c] Element 4");
    maphelp.insert(pair<string,vector<string>>("Element", vect));

    cout << endl;
    vector<string> vect1;
    vect.push_back("[ab] Element1 2");
    vect1.push_back("[a] Element1 1");
    vect1.push_back("[b] Element1 3");
    vect1.push_back("[e] Element1 6");
    vect1.push_back("[d] Element1 5");
    vect1.push_back("[c] Element1 4");
    maphelp.insert(pair<string,vector<string>>("Element1", vect1));

    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
    cout << "This output is not part of the question." << endl;
    cout << "These are just printed variables below for reference:" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Entire map printed.";
    printMap(maphelp);
    cout << endl;


    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("Element");
    cout << "Selective value of map to be printed: " << v[0] << endl;

    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Now below is the original output which doesn't meet what I'm trying to do." << endl;
    printSelectiveMap(v, maphelp);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Now the output I'm trying to get is below, which would be using the printSelectiveAlphabetic() function" << endl;

    //function I'm trying to adjust
    //PrintSelectiveAlphabetic()

    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
    cout << "\tElement [a] Element 1" << endl;
    cout << "\tElement [ab] Element 2" << endl;
    cout << "\tElement [b] Element 3" << endl;
    cout << "\tElement [c] Element 4" << endl;
    cout << "\tElement [d] Element 5" << endl;
    cout << "\tElement [e] Element 6" << endl;
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "So how do I adjust my printSelectiveAlphabetic() function to get this desired output?"<< endl;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to extract the letters inside the square brackets, and use them to sort the results.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should be passing things such as vectors and maps by reference, not by value.  C++ is not Java.  You are incurring a copy of the entire maps and vectors when you pass them by value.  This: `void printSelectiveMap(vector<string> v,` does not pass a reference to `v`.  Instead, a temporary copy is created and passed, and this is the value-semantics C++ has, as opposed to what you may have used in other languages.

Comment: there's only 2 elements in the map...so you should look up how to sort a vector instead?

Comment: Ok, it's Monday, and I admit only a single cup of coffee, so perhaps I'm still not fully coherent, but I've read this twice and still don't get what the intention is. The word "Element" splayed all over the output isn't helping clarify anything, if that was the intent.

Comment: In all honesty, this looks like the Y part of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Ah, good point. I just started trying C++ after doing Java for so long, so my habits from  Java passed on here, thanks for the tip regarding the referencing Paul

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would to use `std::sort` to sort the vector corresponding to `v[0]` to achieve your expected output as shown below:

```
void printSelectiveAlphabetic(vector<string> v, map<string, vector<string>> helpMap) {
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
    
    std::sort(helpMap.at(v[0]).begin(), helpMap.at(v[0]).end()); //sort the vector corresponding to the key v[0]
    for(const std::string& element: helpMap[v[0]])
    {
        std::cout<<v[0] <<" "<<element<<std::endl;
    }
    cout << "\t|"<<endl;
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/wju841kE4) of the above program is:

```
        |
Element [a] Element 1
Element [ab] Element 2
Element [b] Element 3
Element [c] Element 4
Element [d] Element 5
Element [e] Element 6
        |
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/RPdsFWu8M)